# Проверка фото на вертикальность в PHP

Tags: php, изображения, обработка-изображений, jpeg

Столкнулся с интересной проблемой - в моем web-приложении нужно чтобы пользователь загрузил вертикальное изображение, это легко:

```
$file = $_FILES['file'];
$im_php = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);
```

Далее выполняем элементарную проверку на то, какая сторона больше

```
if(imagesx($im_php) < imagesy($im_php)) {
    $res = 1;
} else {
    $res = 0;
}
```

И все работает как часы, но вот незадача, если пользователь сфотографировал горизонтально, а затем обрезал фото так, чтобы сделать вертикальное, то скрипт уже ругается.

В проверке показывает что изображение по прежнему горизонтальное!

Подскажите, как бы вы поступили, чтобы обойти этот момент?

PS: просьба не просить использовать сторонние библиотеки)

UPD: Если юзер снял фото в горизонтали а потом через свой телефонный редактор ее перевернул, как можно одсмотреть в акую сторону он это сделал и сколько раз))) Это бы помогла решить задачу самым изящным способом))

Comment: Приведите ссылки на изображения, на которые ругается ваш скрипт.

Comment: не могу, у нас сайт для похудения, там барышни скидыват свои фото, скажем так в купальниках. Сделал imagerotate() на 270 градусов, теперь скрипт отработает верно в большинстве случаев, но иногда будут фото кверх ногами(

Comment: Если пользователь обрезал горизонтальное на вертикальное, но соотношения сторон остались прежние, то вы тут ничего не поделаете. Фотки не хранят информацию о переворотах (не все форматы), им это не нужно. Если хотите решить проблему изящно, то напишите нейросеть, которая будет определять "вертикальность" (вы же просили без библиотек, так что придётся нейросеть ещё и обучать самостоятельно)

Comment: @ArchDemon да, я сам об этом думал) буду признателен, если скините сцыль на статью или иной ресурс, где делают что то подобное)) Хотя на пхп наверное никто этим не грешит)

Comment: Не очень знаю gdimage, но не может быть такого, что при определении ширины/высоты используется теги из exif изображения, типа автоповорот. Может покопаться в функции exif_read_data() - что она выдает на тех изображениях, что неправильно отображаются? в частности тег Orientation